# iPad UIWebView in JSON Post Error

Tags: c#, ios, json, ipad, uiwebview

Have a WebMethod.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getRez
(
    string otelKod,
    string dil,
    string varisGun,
    string ayrilisGun,
    string yetiskinSayi,
    string cocukSayi,
    string odaTip,
    string yatakTercih,
    string cocukDogumTarih1,
    string cocukDogumTarih2,
    string cocukDogumTarih3,
    string ad,
    string mail,
    string sehir,
    string clubNo,
    string soyad,
    string telefon,
    string uyruk,
    string adres
)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    string hata = "";
    string sonuc = "";
    try
    {
        if ((otelKod != null && otelKod != "") && (dil != null && dil != ""))
        {
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@otel", otelKod);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@dil", dil);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@varisGun", varisGun);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@ayrilisGun", ayrilisGun);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@yetiskinSayi", yetiskinSayi);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@cocukSayi", cocukSayi);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@odaTip", odaTip);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@yatakTercih", yatakTercih);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@cocukDogumTarih1", cocukDogumTarih1);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@cocukDogumTarih2", cocukDogumTarih2);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@cocukDogumTarih3", cocukDogumTarih3);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@ad", ad);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@mail", mail);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@sehir", sehir);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@clubNo", clubNo);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@soyad", soyad);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@telefon", telefon);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@uyruk", uyruk);
            ado.addPrm(ref cm, "@adres", adres);
            if (ado.run(
            "INSERT INTO [rezRapor]" +
            "([otel]" +
            ",[dil]" +
            ",[varisGun]" +
            ",[ayrilisGun]" +
            ",[yetiskinSayi]" +
            ",[cocukSayi]" +
            ",[odaTip]" +
            ",[yatakTercih]" +
            ",[cocukDogumTarih1]" +
            ",[cocukDogumTarih2]" +
            ",[cocukDogumTarih3]" +
            ",[ad]" +
            ",[mail]" +
            ",[sehir]" +
            ",[clubNo]" +
            ",[soyad]" +
            ",[telefon]" +
            ",[uyruk]" +
            ",[adres])" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@otel" +
            ",@dil" +
            ",@varisGun" +
            ",@ayrilisGun" +
            ",@yetiskinSayi" +
            ",@cocukSayi" +
            ",@odaTip" +
            ",@yatakTercih" +
            ",@cocukDogumTarih1" +
            ",@cocukDogumTarih2" +
            ",@cocukDogumTarih3" +
            ",@ad" +
            ",@mail" +
            ",@sehir" +
            ",@clubNo" +
            ",@soyad" +
            ",@telefon" +
            ",@uyruk" +
            ",@adres)"
            , cm, ado.cn, null, false, false) != -1)
            {
                sonuc = "Basarili";
            }
            else
            {
                hata = Session["adoSqlError"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        hata = ex.Message;
    }

    if (hata != "")
        return "";
    else
        return hata;
}
```

above have a webmethod..

```
function rezervasyon
    (
        strOtelKod,
        strDilKod,
        strVarisGun,
        strAyrilisGun,
        strYetiskinSayi,
        strCocukSayi,
        strOdaTip,
        strYatakTercih,
        strCocukDogumTarih1,
        strCocukDogumTarih2,
        strCocukDogumTarih3,
        strAd,
        strMail,
        strSehir,
        strClubNo,
        strSoyad,
        strTelefon,
        strUyruk,
        strAdres
    ) {
    var veri =
    {
        otelKod: strOtelKod,
        dil: strDilKod,
        varisGun: strVarisGun,
        ayrilisGun: strAyrilisGun,
        yetiskinSayi: strYetiskinSayi,
        cocukSayi: strCocukSayi,
        odaTip: strOdaTip,
        yatakTercih: strYatakTercih,
        cocukDogumTarih1: strCocukDogumTarih1,
        cocukDogumTarih2: strCocukDogumTarih2,
        cocukDogumTarih3: strCocukDogumTarih3,
        ad: strAd,
        mail: strMail,
        sehir: strSehir,
        clubNo: strClubNo,
        soyad: strSoyad,
        telefon: strTelefon,
        uyruk: strUyruk,
        adres: strAdres
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Servis/services.asmx/getRez",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: $.toJSON(veri),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert($(".onayMesaji").text());
            $(".jsonkod").html($.toJSON(veri));
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(" Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

ERROR IMG : https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bgdf1wmIUAAfb4_.jpg

I'm doing this but "json parse error unrecognized token '< ' problem."
why I'm getting such an error?

And localhost no problem..

But I'm getting error when I upload to the server project..

And json result;

```
{
  "otelKod": "101",
  "dil": "en-EN",
  "varisGun": "",
  "ayrilisGun": "",
  "yetiskinSayi": "1",
  "cocukSayi": "1",
  "odaTip": "108",
  "yatakTercih": "Single Bed",
  "cocukDogumTarih1": "",
  "cocukDogumTarih2": "",
  "cocukDogumTarih3": "",
  "ad": "",
  "mail": "",
  "sehir": "",
  "clubNo": "",
  "soyad": "",
  "telefon": "",
  "uyruk": "",
  "adres": ""
}
```

What should I do?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just step through the code and examine the json string. You can copy it to jsonlint.com to check it.